# Find the set of feasible directions

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the problem of minimizing $c'x$ over the set $P = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n:Ax=b,Dx \leq f, Ef \leq g \right\}$. Let $x^*$ be an element of $P$ that satisfies $Dx^*=f$, $Ex^*<g$. Show that the set of feasible directions at the point $x^*$ is the set $$\left\{ d \in \mathbb{R}^n:Ad=0,Dd \leq 0 \right\}.$$
I have problems with sketching out the methods of doing this type of Optimization problem. Please help me, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $d\in\mathbb R^n$ is a feasible direction at the point $x^*\in P$, that is, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $x^* + d\varepsilon\in P$. Since $Ax^*=b$, it is clear that we must have $Ad=0$ for $A(x^*+d\varepsilon)=b$ to hold. Similarly, since $Dx^*=f$, we must have $Dd\leqslant0$ for $D(x^*+d\varepsilon)\leqslant f$ to hold.